# Can we write limits variable-free?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-topology

When first learning the subject and when doing simple calculations, it's convenient to describe derivatives in terms of variables, i.e.
$$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f'(x)$$
and we say the derivative takes a "function" (expression) and maps it to another "function" (expression). But more rigorously, we can say that given an $n$-manifold $M$, a chart $x:U\subseteq M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, and a function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f \equiv \partial_i(f\circ x^{-1})\circ x$$
This is just one way of reformalizing derivatives, but what we have done is taken out the reliance on a naive notion of "variables". I was wondering if we have made any similar re-formulations for the limit. From the above equivalence, we need the notion of a limit to fully describe the partial derivative on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I.e. for a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$$ \partial_ig(a_1,...,a_i,...,a_n)\equiv \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(a_1,...,a_i-h,...,a_n)-g(a_1,...,a_i,...,a_n)}{h} $$
You could use an "epsilon-delta" definition of limits if $n=1$ and you want to totally-order $\mathbb{R}$ or you could define limits using neighborhoods or open sets, but the notation is what I'm stuck on. Is there a way to formalize the limit as a map
$$ \lim_{i,\ b}:\ C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)\ \to\ C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) $$
$$ \left(\lim_{i,\ b}g\right)(a_1,...,a_i,...,a_n)\equiv\ ``\,\lim_{a_i\to b}\left(g(a_1,...,a_i,...,a_n)\right)" $$
similar to the many ways we have reformatted the derivative? For clarity, my question is this:

**Question:** Is there a definition of the limit on Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$ space that doesn't require variables? If not, is there simply a notion of a limit that doesn't use variables in its notation?

Comment: How familiar are you with the topological definitions of limits, particularly the usage of nets and such? That seems at least along the lines of what you're looking for...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm familiar with the definition of limit of a function $f:X\to Y$ for topological spaces $X$ and $Y$... For every open set $U$ of $X$ containing $p$, there's an open set $V$ of $Y$ such that the image of $U$ under $f$ is a subset of $V$. I'm pretty sure that's the definition I remember. I see that generalization to nets uses a variable-free notation, but how then would you notate the limit of the difference quotient? The traditional notation allows for "embedded" variables, but I can't find a way that represents this in a variable-free notation.

Comment: "that doesn't require variables": what do you mean ? Even in the notation of derivatives there are variables.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean exactly what I say and the notation for derivatives in fact does not use variables; e.g. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ only includes the symbols $\partial$, $x$, and $i$; $\partial$ is simply a symbol that helps us conceptually but it's certainly not a variable, $x$ is a chart which is a specific element of the atlas of the manifold so that's not a variable either, and $i$ is a specific integer between $1$ and $n$ so that's not a variable either.

Comment: "$x$ is a chart which is a specific element of the atlas of the manifold so that's not a variable ": wow, I am afraid I have nothing to do here.

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine, Jakub Marian, developed a coordinate free notation in calculus in his bachelor thesis: [Alternative mathematical notation and
its applications in calculus](https://jakubmarian.com/data/bachelor_thesis.pdf)
He was pretty good so there should be very good ideas.

I am looking at it now and he only treats calculus of 1 variable! You can do the case of $n$-variables yourself :-)

A crucial role is played by the identity function $\iota(x) = x$ which he uses to write compositions efficiently; e.g., the simple expression $(\iota^3+\iota^2 + \iota)\circ(\iota^3 + 2\iota)\circ(\iota^2 + 8\iota + 4\iota^2)$ in his notation corresponds to a crazy polynomial in the variable $x$.
He views $\lim_a$ as an operator on functions (he uses the "undefined" symbol $\Omega$ if the limit does not exist).
He has the "difference quotient with step $h$" operator $\Delta_h$ and defines "indefinite sums with step $h$" as $\sum_h = (\Delta_h)^{-1}$ (defined up to the set of $h$-periodic functions).
Based on this, he develops a theory of the derivative $\partial$ and the integration $\int$ (in the sense of an inverse to $\partial$) and rewrites the classical theorems in this notation. 
He illustrates at many places how his notation simplifies some computations.

However, I can not imagine any real application of it in the sense of gathering more information about spaces of functions, etc.
On the other hand, I was once thinking of using similar abstractions when I was supposed to compute some crazy integrals in my research and had the suspicion that there is a hidden structure which I just didn't see when looking at the crazy coordinate expressions. Such notation is also better if you communicate with a machine; e.g., from my experience, Mathematica and Haskell think about expressions in this way. It is probably very much related to $\lambda$-calculus but I am not an expert on that.

Comment: This is interesting, but I did not see the definition of the notation $\Delta_\bullet$ (used in Definition 2.19). The definition $\partial = \lim_0 \Delta_h$ made sense, but it still has the variable $h$, while think the idea of this question is to eliminate $h$.

Comment: He defines it in Definitions 2.10 and 2.11 (limit of a family of functions and a family of operators). It would be probably more elegant at this point to have the generalization for n variables.

Comment: So the answer is actually that $\Delta_\bullet$ is _not_ defined as an independent notation, the way $\Delta_h$ is; instead it is defined only in conjunction with the $\lim$ symbol. It seems a little strained, though the earlier definitions such as $\lim_a$ seemed intuitive enough.

Comment: I would understand $\Delta_\bullet$ independenly as a family of operators $\Delta_{h}$ for $h\in \mathbb{R}$, i.e., a particular set. He defines the limit of a family of operators, e.g., $\lim_0 \Delta_\bullet$, as the operator associating to a function $f$ the function which is the limit of the family of functions $\Delta_h f$. The limit of a family of functions $g_h$ is then defined pointwise like $(\lim_0 g_h)(x) := \lim_0 (g_h(x))$.

Comment: Correction of the last sentence: The limit of a family of functions $g_\bullet$ is then defined pointwise as the function $(\lim_0 g_{\bullet})(x) = \lim_0 (g_{\bullet}(x))$. Again, I see a possibility of making this better by developing the formalism for more variables so that $\Delta_\bullet$ can be interpreted as an operator from functions of $1$ variable to functions of $2$ variables.

Comment: One could then write $\partial := \lim^1_0 \Delta$, where $\lim^1_0$ is the limit at $0$ with respect to the first variable.